# DRF M2M Nested Serializer Field Incorrectly Typed as String

Tags: django, python-3.x, django-models, django-rest-framework, graphene-python

Whenever I attempt to deserialize a list of Technology objects while creating a TechnologyStack I receive the message:

> Field \"technologies\" of type \"String\" must not have a sub selection.

I'm using djangorestframework==3.8.2. Anyone know what's causing this and/or a potential solution?

Also, please note that I'm using the graphene-django library. But, it seems this problem is attributable to the drf serializer.

```
class TechnologyProfile(models.Model):
    user = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    name = models.CharField(max_length=100, unique=True)


class Technology(models.Model):
    user = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    profile = models.ForeignKey(TechnologyProfile, blank=True, null=True, on_delete=models.CASCADE)

    class Meta:
        verbose_name_plural = "technologies"


class TechnologyStack(models.Model):
    technologies = models.ManyToManyField(Technology, related_name='technology_stacks')


class TechnologyProfileSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    user_id = RelayIdField()
    name = serializers.CharField()

    class Meta:
        model = TechnologyProfile
        fields = ('id', 'name', 'user_id')


class TechnologySerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    user_id = RelayIdField()
    profile = TechnologyProfileSerializer(many=False)

    class Meta:
        model = Technology
        fields = '__all__'


class TechnologyStackSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    technologies = TechnologySerializer(many=True)

    class Meta:
        model = TechnologyStack
        read_only_fields = ('id',)
        fields = '__all__'
```